# how to use meta tag in Android manifest for google Map and GCM service

Tags: android, google-maps, android-manifest, google-cloud-messaging

When i go to implement Google GCM and google Map together,how to manage meta tag on the manifest?

for GCM, they mention something like this.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="1110000" />
```

for Google map,they mention something like this.

```
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="API_KEY" />
```

how do i use this both in the same manifest file in my app.

Comment: add all the meta tags they are independent of each other however putting two meta tags for google play services for maps and gcm is not required one is sufficient

Comment: yes,i did like this way.thanks

Answer (score 0):

There isn't problem to use the both, because are independent data.